C++ macro preprocessor string concatenation
I've read the various other questions on this but they either don't work or I'm otherwise stuck.
I'm trying to dynamically #import a file based on build flags where my imported file name is of the form:
hardware_<hardware>_<version>.h
I can make it work, but only without the .h file extension, which isn't ideal.
How do I modify this to have .h on the end?
./hardware_XXX_YYY:
#define FOO "bar"

./main.cpp:
#include <iostream>   

#define HARDWARE XXX
#define HARDWARE_VERSION YYY

#define CCC(x) #x

// This fails:
//#define BBB(ha, ver) CCC(hardware_##ha##_##ver##.h)

// This works:
#define BBB(ha, ver) CCC(hardware_##ha##_##ver)

#define AAA(ha, ver) BBB(ha, ver)

#include AAA(HARDWARE, HARDWARE_VERSION)

int main() {
    
    std::cout << FOO  << '\n';
}


BTW, if you omit the last ## before .h, it will generate the desired output. #define BBB(ha, ver) CCC(hardware_##ha##_##ver.h)

@john It is supported. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include item 3. What is not supported is when #include comes from macro expansion.

The preprocessor seems to form hardware_XXX_YYY. instead of hardware_XXX_YYY.h. Why and why is the first form not a valid preprocessor token?

The standard requires that the token pasting results in a valid token. (described e.g. in https://complete-concrete-concise.com/programming/c/preprocessor-the-token-pasting-operator/) In general, there is the distinction of identifiers and punctuation. Thus, concatenating a sequence of characters (identifier?) with a dot (punctuation?) might be invalid. In so far, the answer to drop the ## before .h makes sense somehow. (I must admit the weak part of this whole reasoning: I never considered how this all applies to #include paths...)

@7478597 the implicit is that if there is a punctuator, its lhs and rhs should be valid token? It make sense but I couldn't wrap my head around this by reading the standard. It would be why the removal of ## works: hardware_##ha##_##ver gives a valid " subtoken, h also and they are linked by a puctuator? Is it correct?

The rule of thumb is that if it won't otherwise form another valid identifier, you don't need ##. ## in a##b is necessary because a and b would otherwise form an identifier ab (and expanded in the macro as that if possible). ## in ver##.h is not needed because ver.h cannot possibly be parsed as a single identifier.

Looks like a job for a small code generator were you generate a small include file that contains the actual hardware_<hardware>_<version>.h for you. This header file will be so small you probably can generate it from a script that reads some version info.

You don't need the extra ## before the .h part, as the .h is not part of the token parsing (the ha and ver is, and you need an extra ## because of the underscore).
Here is a tiny example that includes "string.h" built up by macros. Again, st and .h is not part of the concatenating, therefore no need for extra ##s.
#include <iostream>   

#define CCC(x) #x
#define BBB(ha, ver) CCC(st##ha##ver.h)

#include BBB(ri,ng)

int main() {
    
    std::cout << BBB(ri,ng)"\n";
}

Output:
string.h

I'm sure id tried that permutation at some point and had it not work. must have had some other issue in the fray of trying to get something working. Thanks

st is part of the concatenation. Whether the identifier is replaced in the macro expansion is another entirely different matter.
